# Store binary content into sqlite db

Tags: c#, binary

I store image into sqlite database . Type specified is BLOB fir the image field. Below is the code for storing it,

```
FileInfo uploadedFileInfo = new FileInfo(Filename);
FileStream fs = fileInfo.OpenRead();
byte[] content = new byte[fs.Length];
fs.Read(content, 0, content.Length);
fs.Close();
```

And store this content into db. Sometimes file up;oad fails.
This c# code is running as windows service in 64 bit machine. Target is AnyCPU.
Is there something wrong in the code. Or do i need to set the target as x86. Ant feedback is welcome!.
Regards

Comment: what error do you get? post the error!

Comment: Well aside from anything else, you're ignoring the return value of `Read`, which is never a good idea. But you've given us *no indication* of what "sometimes file upload fails"  means.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite is a native component, therefore you need to put interop.dlls into seperate folders (Below System.Data.SQLite.dll)

```
/System.Data.SQLite.dll (core assembly)
/x86/SQLite.Interop.dll (x86 native interop assembly)
/x64/SQLite.Interop.dll (x64 native interop assembly)
```